# Entity Framework: Model for Categories/Products relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following model of data for Entity Framework.

I have abstract Product. Every Product relates with one Category of products. For example:

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And there are concrete products:

```
public class ConcreteProduct1 : Product
{
    // some specific member
}

public class ConcreteProduct2 : Product
{
    // some specific member
}

//etc.
```

I have hierarchical Categories, for example:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Every Category has `ICollection<Product> Products`.

**Problem**: Category should be related with only products some concrete product type. I.e. I need be able get *Concrete Products* into Category, for example:

```
public Category<ConcreteProduct1> GetCategory<ConcreteProduct1> ()
{
    // should return Category that contain ICollection<ConcreteProduct1>
}
```

How I can describe this restriction in my Entity Framework model? Or may be there are some best practice for building these relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to answer because it depends too much on the requisites of your project.

There are three different approaches to representing an inheritance hierarchy:

**Table per Hierarchy ([TPH](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx))**: Enable polymorphism by denormalizing the SQL schema, and utilize a type discriminator column that holds type information.

**Table per Type ([TPT](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx))**: Represent "is a" (inheritance) relationships as "has a" (foreign key) relationships.

**Table per Concrete class ([TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx))**: Discard polymorphism and inheritance relationships completely from the SQL schema.

You should check the links and find what is the best suitable model for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use lists and a categorymanager:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
}

public static class CategoryManager
{
    public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
}

public Product test = new Product
{
    Id = 1
};

public Category add = new Category
{
    Id = 1
};

public void Init()
{
    add.Products.Add(test);
    CategoryManager.Categories.Add(add);
}

public Product GetByID(Category cat, string val)
{
   return cat.Where(x => x.Id == val).ToArray()[0];
}

public Category GetCat(Product pro)
{
    foreach (var cat in CategoryManager.Categories)
    {
       if (cat == pro) return cat;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but, unfortunately, I can't understand your answer :) My question related with Entity Framewrok model, i.e. it relates to ORM - how to represent into database my domain model, which describe by C# code by Entity Framework Code First. My problem - I need not get parent Product by Category, I need get concrete products by Category. I will clarify my question.